# How to get the RECT during Windows Minimize, Maximize and Restore animation

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-runtime, dwm

Hi I am developing a project using C#/WPF and `Windows.UI.Composition` for creating acrylic effect in WPF.

Here is how my project looks like currently

[image: Sample image]

#### Current Status

Usually rendering any `Windows.UI.Composition` visual in WPF causes airspace issue, to overcome this I created separate window to render acrylic and another window to render WPF content and overlapped one over the other. Since using `SetWindowPos()` is slow and causes flicker, I created a Layered Transparent Window of full width and height, and clips the `Windows.UI.Composition.Visual` to the size of the window which have the WPF Content.

#### Current Issue

But when I maximize, restore or minimize a window, the animation is lost and so I tried creating  custom maximize, minimize and restore animations using `Windows.UI.Composition` but the Custom animation is never same as the original one.(I mean it is not syncing with each other). The `GetWindowRect()` function only gives the maximized window RECT not the RECT values during the animation.

**So Is there any way to get the RECT value during window maximize, minimize and Restore animations so I can apply it to the Clipping Function?**

### Code

This is the Code I used to animate the visual containing acrylic:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Composition;
using Windows.UI.Composition.Core;

namespace FluentCompositor.Core
{
    public class VisualAnimator
    {
        #region AnimationTypes
        public const int ANIMATION_MAXIMIZE = 0;
        public const int ANIMATION_RESTORE = 1;
        public const int ANIMATION_MINIMIZE = 2;
        #endregion

        #region MaximizeAnimation
        Vector3KeyFrameAnimation maximizeAnimation;
        #endregion

        Visual animationVisual;
        CompositorController compositionController;
        Compositor compositor;

        public VisualAnimator(Visual visual,CompositorController controller,IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            animationVisual = visual;
            compositionController = controller;
            compositor = controller.Compositor;
            maximizeAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
        }

        public void Animate(int animatonType)
        {
            switch(animatonType)
            {
                case ANIMATION_MAXIMIZE:
                    AnimateMaximize();
                    break;
            }
            compositionController.Commit();
        }

        private void AnimateMaximize()
        {
            var easeOut = compositor.CreateCubicBezierEasingFunction(new Vector2(.215f, 0.610f), new Vector2(0.355f, 1.000f));
            animationVisual.Scale = new Vector3(.945f, .945f, .945f);
            Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(animationVisual.Size / 2, 0);
            
            animationVisual.CenterPoint = v3 + new Vector3(280, 0, 0);
            maximizeAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0f, new Vector3(.945f, .945f, .945f), easeOut);
            maximizeAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), easeOut);
            maximizeAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
            maximizeAnimation.Direction = AnimationDirection.Normal;
            animationVisual.StartAnimation("Scale", maximizeAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code I mentioned above, I used scale animation to animate visual like Window Maximize animation. This method use scaling instead of clipping.

The clipping function code:

```
private void ClipCompositionRoot(int x,int y,int cx,int cy,bool commit)
{
    if (clipRect != null)
    {
        clipRect.Offset = new Vector2(x, y);
        clipRect.Size = new Vector2(cx, cy);
        if(commit)
        {
            compositionController.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

So if I could get the Animation RECT values I could pass it to this function to clip my acrylic visual along with the window Animation.

**Will it be possible using any DWM Private Functions or something similar?**

Comment: The animation is just a drawing thing, I don't think the HWND changes.

Comment: it is not related to handles, i am trying to get the RECT values of window maximize,minimize and restore animations